# Updating multiple rows on a large handsontable locks chrome

Tags: handsontable

I have a handson table with 300+. It renders quickly. However, if I update one column in all rows like so:

```
function() {
    console.trace("Start", new Date());
    $scope.myData.forEach(function(elem, idx) {
        elem.properties.myCol = Math.random();
        if (idx % 100 == 0) console.trace("Tick", new Date());
    });
    console.trace("End", new Date());
};
```

The loop executes in less than a second, but the browser tab locks up and the page does not update for over a minute. Is there some way I can disable handsontable from reading updates to the array and then triggering a manual redraw? Is there any other way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option that was slowing down rendering was `columnSorting: true,`. Removing this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the handsontable data you can use
     $('#yourTable').handsontable("render");
To re-render the handsontable manually after any updates to the data. And set **observeChanges:false** (It is false by default) while creating handsontable to disable automatic re-rendering by handsontable.

Comment: But how do I stop it from automatically rendering the data 300 times in the first place?

Comment: I don't know why your handsontable is re-rendering  by itself, by default it won't. You can keep the data as global variable and call the render function after updating the data.

Comment: did you set **observeChanges:true** while creating handsontable, just change it to False, then it won't re-render automatically.

Comment: See my accepted self answer. I did need to render manually likeyou said, but the column sorting was what locked my browser.